# Decreasing certain amount of time from a selected time

Tags: php

Friends, I decided to create a PHP program with PostgreSQL as back end . In this, I would like to create a page which shows some timetable (schedule) and from which user has to select one option using a radio button. and I need to pass the "selected time - 15 minutes" to a certain field in database.The technique I used is shown below

```
     $a=$dt[$m].' '.$ftime;
     for($j=1;$j<=$slots;$j++)
    {   
    echo "<td>";
    if($j==1)
    {   
    $a= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$a + 0 minutes"));
    $value= date("Y-m-d^H:i:s", strtotime("$a + 0 minutes"));
    }
    else
    {
    $a= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$a + $intl minutes"));
    $value= date("Y-m-d^H:i:s", strtotime("$a + $intl minutes"));   
    }  
    $b=explode(" ",$a);  
    if(!in_array($a,$res_tm))   
    echo "<input type='radio' name='radio1' value=$value> $b[1]";
    else echo "Reserved";
```

I have done the db operations in another page using a form tag. But the problem is that I wanna store the correct value.But in this, I am getting a value which is always the increment of the selected value by an amount of `$intl` (which is 15 minutes). But I want to pass the correct value. I figured out that value of `$value` is always `$intl` minutes greater than the actual value, But I couldn't correct that..
Anyone please help me

Comment: You are always adding minutes `strtotime("$a + $intl minutes"))` Should that be subtracting them?

Comment: What i mean is that i have to a start a list of schedule from 10am to 12 pm.which is incrementing through 15 minutes
but if a user selcets 10:15:00 The value stored through that radio button will be 10:30:00 which is incorrect. Thats the real problem. So i wanna a code to reduce $intl minutes from the variable $value
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because your $intl in the "else" part starts at 2 instead of 1.
Try to substract 1 (or 15) from it each time you go through the "else" part.

```
if($j==1)
{   
   // Here you want $intl == 0, which is $j - 1.
   // Actually, you can drop the '+ 0 minutes' altogether
   $a= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$a"));
   $value= date("Y-m-d^H:i:s", strtotime("$a"));
}
else
{
   // I am guessing here, since I don't know the contents of $intl or $j.
   // You probably need either $intl - 1 or $j - 1.
   $intl_adjusted = $intl - 1;
   $a= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$a + $intl_adjusted minutes"));
   $value= date("Y-m-d^H:i:s", strtotime("$a + $intl_adjusted minutes"));   
}
```